# Migrating React ES6 to TypeScript: import statements don't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, definitelytyped

I have a React project currently written in ES6 which I am migrating to TypeScript. I'm having trouble with the `import` statements.

Currently with ES6 I installed React dependencies using NPM, ex `npm install react`, and use Babel with Browserify to build an output ES5 bundle. (Using Browserify is not a requirement, I'm just trying to get TS working with the project.)

A typical React ES6 file looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {Router, Route, Link} from "react-router"
import Button from "./components/Button"

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render(){ 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Moving into TS, I've installed `d.ts` files for all my React dependencies using [`tsd install react/`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react), set TSC `module: "commonjs"` and `jsx: "react"`, converted a few files from `*.jsx` to `*.tsx`, and I get these compile errors on the `import` statements:

> Error:(1, 8) TS1192: Module '"react"' has no default export.

The `import Button` statement gives no error. It seems TSC is unable to resolve the NPM module dependencies.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I'm facing issue other way round. I have a library which was built in TypeScript. I made a build out of it and trying to import the js file. The localhost:3000 works well for me. But when I do `npm run build`, it says that ts-file-transpiled.js has someFunc() which isn't correctly exported. I don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TypeScript 1.8+**

Compile with [`--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)—add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to *tsconfig.json*

*Note:* this doesn't work for me when setting `module` in *tsconfig.json* to `commonjs` though.

**Alternatively...**

Use this instead:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Router from "react-router";

// use React, Router.Router, Router.Route, and Router.Link here
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3337) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-83694181). Currently [`react.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/813f3b03dbaa53acb9bbe8428a6c5137a26795d6/react/react.d.ts#L878) uses `export =` and so you need to import it by doing `import * as React`.

Basically these libraries only have one export. That's representing in the definition file with `export =`.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Still a little foggy on what the difference is. What about `{Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router'`? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Accepted. :) Still a bit confused, though... so the reason `* as` is needed is because the `d.ts` uses `export =`, but I thought that was equivalent to ES6 `export default` which would be imported using `import React from 'react'`? It's unclear to me why it worked with Babel/Browserify but the semantics seemingly changed with TSC. I guess its a difference in how modules are resolved?

Comment: I'm also unsure about the `ReactRouter.Router` syntax. The existing JS code worked as `Router` so how will `import * as ReactRouter` work at runtime?

Comment: Looking at the Babel transpiled code I see that for all my default imports (`import React from 'react'`) is uses `react2 = _interopRequireDefaultExport(react)` that checks `__esModule` and does some transformation I don't fully understand, then my code references React through the transformed `react2` variable. I don't see anything similar in the TSC transpiled code. I'm guessing this is the difference. My head is spinning. :)

Comment: Aha! I found out I can can do `import Router from 'react-router/lib/Router'`. This is good with me.

Comment: I take it back, while TSC liked `import Router from 'react-router/lib/Router'` the transpiled JS did not work. It compiled references to `Router` as `Router.default`, which is wrong -- the `Router` reference itself is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the following syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
```

You need to set these two flags in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{ "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, "esModuleInterop": true }
```

Tested with the following versions:
Typescript 2.9.2
@types/react 16.4.7
react 16.4.1