# Default function export type definition

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to write a typing definition for [pouch-redux-middleware](https://github.com/pgte/pouch-redux-middleware), which exports a single function:

```
import PouchMiddleware from 'pouch-redux-middleware'

PouchMiddleware({...})
```

Here is the typings definition I have:

```
interface PouchMiddleware {
  (a: any): any;
}

declare var PouchMiddleware: PouchMiddleware;

declare module "pouch-redux-middleware" {
  export = PouchMiddleware;
}
```

This results in the error:

> Module '"pouch-redux-middleware"' has no default export.

What is the correct way to declare this?

Answer (score 8):

For transpiling to commonjs modules, you might just have to change the definition file to:

```
declare function PouchMiddleware(a: any): any;

declare module "pouch-redux-middleware" {
    export = PouchMiddleware;
}
```

Then import it like so:

```
import PouchMiddleware = require("pouch-redux-middleware");
```

Kind of sucks though. Someone might come along with a better answer.

---

I believe my previous answer here only works for targeting ES6 and setting the module as "ES2015":

> You will need to compile with [`--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in order to get it to work and then change the interface in the definition file to a function:
>
> ```
> declare function PouchMiddleware(a: any): any;
>
> declare module "pouch-redux-middleware" {
>     export = PouchMiddleware;
> }
> ```
>
> A similar thing happens with the react library. [Read more
>   here...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33793875/188246)

Comment: Thanks, although with the option I get `Cannot find name 'PouchMiddleware` when I try to call it. TypeScript's error messages are just awful..but I guess something is wrong in the definition.

Comment: Adding `declare var PouchMiddleware: PouchMiddleware;` makes it compile, but fails at runtime: `pouch_redux_middleware_1.default is not a function`.

Comment: @jgillich I updated my answer. I'm not sure why it adds the `.default` when setting the module type to "commonjs".

Comment: This one also gives me `pouch_redux_middleware_1.default is not a function`, unfortunately.

Comment: @jgillich yeah ok, I give up on this one. I believe in the past I've seen people recommending to not use ES6 imports and do: `import PouchMiddleware = require("pouch-redux-middleware");`

Answer (score 0):

In general you can export and import the class using following structure.

```
module pouch-redux-middleware {
     export class pouch {

     }
}
```

To use exported class, you need to write:-

```
import {pouch} from 'FileName'
```

Regards

Ajay

Comment: I can't change what's exported tho.

Comment: if you want to make .d.ts file of pouch-redux-middleware and then refer angular-material.d.ts file for a sample file. They don't have exported member in their .d.ts file.